# How to update code of my existing altcoin?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, altcoin-development, cryptonote

I have an altcoin with 10 miners.

I want to update some changes in the code. with new rules of blockreward.

I have created new code also.

But how to make changes effect in the current blockchain, so that all miners follow these rules